# Draw the closest Bone (Shoulder - Head) of 2 tracking skeletons Kinect SDK v1.6

Tags: kinect, closest

I'm looking a solution to draw the bone of the closest skeleton. I wrote code to draw the first tracking skeleton's bone. If the second person will closer than first I want to draw bone of second skeleton. Maybe somebody have any idea how to do it?

```
void sensor_SkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        // check for frame drop.
        if (skeletonFrame == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        // copy the frame data in to the collection
        skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(totalSkeleton);

        // get the first Tracked skeleton
        skeleton = (from trackskeleton in totalSkeleton
                              where trackskeleton.TrackingState == SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked
                              select trackskeleton).FirstOrDefault();


        if (skeleton != null)
        {
            if (skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked && skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head].TrackingState == JointTrackingState.Tracked)
            {
                myCanvas.Children.Clear();
                this.DrawHead();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Draws the head.
private void DrawHead()
{
    if (skeleton != null)
    {
        drawBone(skeleton.Joints[JointType.ShoulderCenter], skeleton.Joints[JointType.Head]);
    }
}


// Draws the bone.
void drawBone(Joint trackedJoint1, Joint trackedJoint2)
{
    Line skeletonBone = new Line();
    skeletonBone.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    skeletonBone.StrokeThickness = 3;

    Point joint1 = this.ScalePosition(trackedJoint1.Position);
    skeletonBone.X1 = joint1.X;
    skeletonBone.Y1 = joint1.Y;

    Point joint2 = this.ScalePosition(trackedJoint2.Position);
    skeletonBone.X2 = joint2.X;
    skeletonBone.Y2 = joint2.Y;

    myCanvas.Children.Add(skeletonBone);
}

/// <summary>
/// Scales the position.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="skeletonPoint">The skeltonpoint.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private Point ScalePosition(SkeletonPoint skeletonPoint)
{
    // return the depth points from the skeleton point
    DepthImagePoint depthPoint = this.sensor.CoordinateMapper.MapSkeletonPointToDepthPoint(skeletonPoint, DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
    return new Point(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y);
}
```

Comment: adjusted indent of code

Answer (score 0):

define a certain threshold and if the bone is behind that threshold draw the joins x,y coordinates on the canvas. You will have to add code to update the position of the sprite accordingly.